# Sencha application access on Blackberry z10 mobile browser

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch-2, blackberry-10

I have a sencha app which is kept at a location on server.
The application can be accessed by hitting the url on any mobile browser.
Say, the URL is http://www.myserver.com/myapp

I am able to access the application appropriately on Android native browser, Google Chrome and Safari browser on iPhone.

When I am hitting the same URL on blackberry z10 mobile browser, only the title bar of the application is shown and home screen is not loaded. Only the background of application is visible

Appreciate any help. Thanks a ton.

Comment: Which version of Sencha Touch are you using? (2.1.x, 2.2.x, etc)

Comment: I am using Sencha 2.2

Comment: Touch 2.2 is supposed to support non-Webkit browsers, so the BB10 stock browser should be supported. Without physically seeing the app, it's hard to speculate about what is happening.

Comment: Have you tried to debug your web app? You can try this https://developer.blackberry.com/html5/documentation/web_inspector_overview_1553586_11.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the concern arthurakay and kio21. 
My homescreen panel has following css property applied to it for avoiding flickering effect.

```
.clsHomePanel{
padding:2% 0 0 0;
-webkit-perspective: 1000;
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;   <- This was the culprit
}
```

Because of the last property , the home screen icons were not visible on BB10 browser. 
When I removed it, home screen loaded properly.